# Browserify-rails can't load js-files containing JSX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, browserify-rails

I have added browserify-rails so that I can get React included in my Rails app.
I'm able to import and export modules. E.g. my `todos.js` executes exported functions from `hello_world.js`. But loading files including JSX breaks everything.

What am I missing? :-(
The entire Rails app is [available at Github](https://github.com/stabenfeldt/rails-react-todo/tree/browserify-rails).
Please see the *browserify-rails* branch.

**application.rb**

`config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = "-t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]"`

**app/assets/javascripts/todos.js**

```
import Hello from "hello_world";
let hello = new Hello();
console.log( "GREET: " + hello.greet() );

// Everything breaks if I add the section below. 
// Why isn't the JSX code transpiled correct? 
// I do have babel in my package.json.
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

**app/assets/javascripts/hello_world.js**

```
class Hello {
  greet() {
    return "Hello world!";
 }
}

export default Hello;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "browserify": "~10.2.4",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install `babel-presets-es2015` also. Just add it in `package.json` with the latest version.